# Ayuda con estos ficheros binarios en C

Tags: c

Tengo dos ficheros binarios hechos en **C**, uno para escribir y otro para leer, al ejecutar el programa de escribir creo que esta todo bien y me lo graba en el fichero, pero al ejecutar el de lectura me sale símbolos y carácteres raros..

Aquí el código de ambos:

**Escritura**

```
struct datos_alumnos{
    int matricula;
    char nombre[30];
    int edad;
}alumnos[2];

int main()
{   
    FILE *fichero;
    fichero = fopen("alumnos.dat","wb");

    if(fichero == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error, el fichero no se puede abrir");
    }

    printf("Introduzca los datos del alumno que desee dar de alta\n\n");
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Nombre del %d%c alumno: ",i+1,167);
        gets(alumnos[i].nombre);
        printf("Su N%c de matricula: ",167);
        scanf("%d",&alumnos[i].matricula);
        printf("Su edad: ");
        scanf("%d",&alumnos[i].edad);
        printf("\n");
        fwrite(alumnos,sizeof(struct datos_alumnos),1,fichero);
    }

    if(fichero != NULL)
    {
        printf("\n\n   DATOS GUARDADOS CORRECTAMENTE");
    }

    fclose(fichero);

    return 0;
```

**Lectura**

```
int main()
{   
    FILE *fichero;
    fichero = fopen("alumnos.dat","rb");

    if(fichero == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error, no se pudo leer el fichero");
    }

    while(!feof(fichero))
    {
        for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
        {
            fread(&alumnos[i],sizeof(struct datos_alumnos),1,fichero);
            printf("%s\n",alumnos[i]);
        }       
    }

    fclose(fichero);

    return 0;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A primera vista, el sospechoso principal sería:

```
printf("%s\n",alumnos[i]);
```

`alumnos[i]` no es un string/char[], es una estructura; y el primer elemento de esta estructura es un `int`<sup>1</sup>. Debería ser algo como:

```
printf("%d %d %s\n", i+1, alumnos[i].matricula, alumnos[i].nombre);
```

El resto del código parece correcto a primera vista. Si sigue habiendo problemas, los puntos a comprobar serían:

- En el primer programa, imprime por pantalla el contenido de la estructura (por ejemplo, con la línea que he puesto yo) para descartar algún error allí.
- Abre el fichero con algún editor de texto básico (Notepad o similares), algunos símbolos serán raros (los correspondientes a los datos numéricos) pero el nombre debería ser bien visible.
- Imprime el valor de sizeof del struct y asegúrate de que el tamaño del fichero sea 2*sizeof.

---

<sup>1</sup>Si el primer elemento fuera el `char[]`, en ciertas arquitecturas podría funcionar.